# Highlighting differences between two strings - modify to show all changes?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to try and highlight the differences between two strings using the code found here:

https://coderwall.com/p/3j2hxq/find-and-format-difference-between-two-strings-in-php

Unfortunately, this code does highlight all of the changes between strings (example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVokk.png). This is also noted in the comments. Is there a way I could modify the code to highlight all differences? I'm somewhat new to PHP, so if anyone has a better open source project that does a similar thing, or can explain to me how I could modify it to show all differences, that'd be great.

Thanks!

```
function get_decorated_diff($old, $new){
    $from_start = strspn($old ^ $new, "\0");        
    $from_end = strspn(strrev($old) ^ strrev($new), "\0");

    $old_end = strlen($old) - $from_end;
    $new_end = strlen($new) - $from_end;

    $start = substr($new, 0, $from_start);
    $end = substr($new, $new_end);
    $new_diff = substr($new, $from_start, $new_end - $from_start);  
    $old_diff = substr($old, $from_start, $old_end - $from_start);

    $new = "$start<ins style='background-color:#ccffcc'>$new_diff</ins>$end";
    $old = "$start<del style='background-color:#ffcccc'>$old_diff</del>$end";
    return array("old"=>$old, "new"=>$new);
}
```

Comment: You wont get teh codez here. You need to do your homework yourself. Probably you need to insert a loop in the above code to trigger it for more than one change.

Comment: This isn't homework, but thanks for the reply. I'm just looking for suggestions as to how I'd go about doing it rather than the finished code itself.

Comment: Well, it's your homework as far as you are concerned. You need to extend the code. It works only for one difference. Multiple differences need to be implemented (it's not that trivial but doable). You might look into open source projects like WinMerge.